# PDO FetchALL returning just one row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is a bit of a headscratcher for me as I have been using PDO for a while without problems. But today I had an issue with this code:

```
  $query = "SELECT exit_time, exit_url FROM exit_log ORDER BY exit_time ASC LIMIT 50";
  $stmt = $db->query($query, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $posts = $stmt->fetchAll();
  print_r($posts);
```

The problem is not with the query itself because on phpMyAdmin the query results in the 50 rows I need. But when I run the code above I get this and just this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [exit_time] => 1366714175 [exit_url] => http://blogbaladi.com/trillium-strikes-again/ )
```

I could almost swear it's the same code I'm using for other projects that work just fine.

Comment: Are you sure that there are more then 1 rows in your table ?

Comment: Are you sure you're hitting the right database server with your PHP code? You could be looking at a production database in PhpMyAdmin and fetching the rows of the development database with your script...

Comment: You're a genius Miklos! put that as a reply so I can accept it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're hitting the right database server with your PHP code? You could be looking at a production database in PhpMyAdmin and fetching the rows of the development database with your script...

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment: What does

```
$query = "SELECT Count(*) as cnt FROM exit_log";
$stmt = $db->query($query, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo __FILE__, '@', __LINE__, "\r\n";
print_r($stmt->fetchAll());


$query = "SELECT exit_time, exit_url FROM exit_log ORDER BY exit_time ASC LIMIT 50";
$stmt = $db->query($query, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$posts = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo __FILE__, '@', __LINE__, "\r\n";
print_r($posts);
```

print?

Comment: Thanks VolkerK, I think Miklos nailed it in the comment above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191012/pdo-fetchall-returning-just-one-row#comment23147469_16191012 , I'm hitting the wrong server with my php code..